# Redirecting issues with spring and springmobile

Tags: spring, spring-mobile

I'm building a website using **Spring** and the **SpringMobile** extension.
I've configured the `LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver` with `mobilePrefix = m/`, `tabletPrefix = t/` and `enableFallback = true`, so that, whenever a dedicated mobile (or tablet) view isn't available, the "normal" (desktop site) view is served.

The site has several sections and subsections. For instance, there's a *Products* section and several *Categories* within it.
Currently, there isn't a landing page for *Products*, so I redirect the user to the first *Category*. In other words, when the link to `/products` is clicked, the corresponding `@Controller` method redirects to `/products/category1` (by returning `"redirect:/products/category1"`); then, the method mapped to `/products/category1`, serves the view (by returning `"viewname"`).

This works as expected when using the desktop site. However, in the mobile site, whenever I try to browse to `/products`, I get automatically redirected to `/m/products` by SpringMobile (which is fine), but then my `@Controller` gets into action, and, instead of being eventually redirected to `/m/products/category1`, strangely I get redirected to `/m/products/m//products/category1`.

Any ideas on why is this happening, and on how to achieve the expected behavior?

P.S.: If I navigate directly to `/m/products/category1`, the desktop view (the fallback) is properly shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out this was a bug in SpringMobile([MOBILE-70](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/MOBILE-70), [MOBILE-78](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/MOBILE-78)) which was fixed in version 1.1.0.RC1. It also affected `forward:` redirection.

I've updated my project dependencies, and the issues appear to be gone for good.